What exactly is this font called or what is similar to it?
Is there any way to find out the name of this font or a font similar to it?


Aster EF is very similar, if not the exact font, or some other variant of Aster perhaps.  It looks like the type has been printed with letterpress so that would explain slight variations in type thickness.  I note that the A and a characters are quite distinctive.
The original designer of Aster was Francesco Simoncini, an Italian font designer who created the font in 1958. So, if you check the date of printing it could help here.
When you have a large sample of text available, Identifont.com can be helpful. It's what I used to find it.  You just basically go through all of the steps to identify specific letter types to narrow down the search.

